# ICE (Interactive Connectivity Establishment) for file sharing

Tags: p2p, file-sharing, stun

how ICE (Interactive Connectivity Establishment) can be used for file sharing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ICE can be used to establish direct connectivity between endpoints.  Thus when you have a connection between endpoints, you can do almost any type of communication including voice, video, and data (which includes transmitting files). Normally ICE may only establish a UDP session between endpoints - so you may have to add a reliability layer on top of UDP for any sort of operation in which packet loss must be accounted for.